# Initialize a swift variable without knowing the type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a notification system for my app and I figured out a way to pass multiple types to my model.

I need to define a target, a second target and a third target in this model. These targets are different types according to the notification type. It looks like something like this:

```
class UserNotification<T1, T2, T3>: Codable {
    let notifyType: String
    let target: T1
    let secondTarget: T2
    let thirdTarget: T3

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case notifyType = "notify_type"
        case target
        case secondTarget = "second_target"
        case thirdTarget = "third_target"
    }
```

It's working well as it is. The thing is I need to define a `notification` variable in on of my views so I can pass notifications from my backend. This is where I'm stuck. How can I define my variable so I can cast types according to my `notifyType` value ?

```
class NotificationBox: UITableViewCell, CellElement {
    private var notification: UserNotification<?, ?, ?> // This is where I'm stuck

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    func setResource(resource: Codable) {
        var notification = resource as! UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
        switch(notification.notifyType) {
            case "get_badge":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Badge, Any>
            case "group_reply":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Message, Debate, Message>
            case "level_unlock":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<User, Any, Any>
            case "get_vote":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Debate, Any>
            case "group_follow_argument":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Message, Debate, Message>
            case "user_follow_level_unlock":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
            case "followed":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
            case "group_invitation_new":
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
            default:
                self.notification = notification as! UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
        }
        configure()
    }
```

Everything is working quite well excepting the variable definition. I don't know how to do it. I tried to define it as:

```
private var notification: UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'UserNotification<Any, Badge, Any>' to type 'UserNotification<Any, Any, Any>'
```

Comment: `T1` is not used anywhere in `UserNotification`? Also, this seems like a use case for an enum with associated values, with each of the `notifyType`s being a `case`. Have you considered that?

Comment: In my opinion you should use an enum with associated variables for this use-case. Makes things much more cleaner and removes most of the ugly type-casting

Comment: Error on my side for T1, I correct it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me how to do something like this ? Never done that @Schottky

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that in cases like `get_badge`, you don't care about `target` and `thirdTarget`, and only `secondTarget` has a defined value?

Comment: In case where targets are not defined as Any, I care about the defined value of targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use definitely use an enum with associated values here. As Schottky said in their answer, you'll need a custom `Codable` implementation. Here's an example, implementing just 4 of the cases, assuming that `User`, `Badge`, `Message`, `Debate` are all `Codable`.

```
enum UserNotification: Codable {
    case getBadge(Badge)
    case groupReply(Message, Debate, Message)
    case levelUnlock(User)
    case userFollowLevelUnlock
    
    var notifyType: String {
        switch self {
        case .getBadge:
            return "get_badge"
        case .groupReply:
            return "group_reply"
        case .levelUnlock:
            return "level_unlock"
        case .userFollowLevelUnlock:
            return "user_follow_level_unlock"
        }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        /*
         When decoding/encoding, use convertFromSnakeCase/convertToSnakeCase to convert the key names to/from snake case
         No need to hard code them here
         e.g.
         let decoder = JSONDecoder()
         decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
         */
        case notifyType
        case target
        case secondTarget
        case thirdTarget
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(notifyType, forKey: .notifyType)
        switch self {
        case .getBadge(let badge):
            // you can also encode the unused targets here if your backend needs them
            try container.encode(badge, forKey: .secondTarget)
        case .groupReply(let msg1, let debate, let msg2):
            try container.encode(msg1, forKey: .target)
            try container.encode(debate, forKey: .secondTarget)
            try container.encode(msg2, forKey: .thirdTarget)
        case .levelUnlock(let user):
            try container.encode(user, forKey: .target)
        case .userFollowLevelUnlock:
            break // nothing more to encode in this case
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notifyType) {
        case "get_badge":
            self = .getBadge(
                try container.decode(Badge.self, forKey: .secondTarget)
            )
        case "group_reply":
            self = .groupReply(
                try container.decode(Message.self, forKey: .target),
                try container.decode(Debate.self, forKey: .secondTarget),
                try container.decode(Message.self, forKey: .thirdTarget)
            )
        case "level_unlock":
            self = .levelUnlock(
                try container.decode(User.self, forKey: .target)
            )
        case "user_follow_level_unlock":
            self = .userFollowLevelUnlock
        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .notifyType, in: container, debugDescription: "Unknown notifyType")
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the `notification` property can just be:

```
private var notification: UserNotification
```

and `setResource` is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the comments: I think that a better approach could be to use an enum with associated data; something like this:

```swift
enum Notification {
    case badge(Badge)
    case groupReply(message: Message, debate: Debate, reply: Message)
    case followed
    // ...
}
```

If you want to know which notification you have (and also get the associated data), you can do it like so:

```swift
switch notification {
    case .badge(let badge):
        // badge is now a let of type Badge
    case .groupReply(let message, _, let reply):
        // you typically ignore unrelated stuff with _
    case .followed:
}
```

This has the downside that currently you have to provide your own `Codable` conformance. This feature has been implemented for the next update of swift, however.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about [SE-0295](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0295-codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values.md) at the end there? That won't generate/parse the same JSON as what OP's `UserNotification` class currently generates, though. I guess if OP can change their implementation of the backend that's all fine.